# R Studio - Cannot use Python in R Markdown - 'This version of Python was compiled for 64bit'

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, rstudio, 32bit-64bit

I am learning R/R Markdown. I am using Windows 10 (64-bit), and have Python 3.9.5 installed on my system.

**When I try to 'knit' an R Markdown document with some Python code**, such as this:

````
```{python}

print(7 + 3)

```
````

It results in this **error**:

> 'Error: Your current architecture is 32bit; however, this version of
> Python was compiled for 64bit. Use reticulate::install_miniconda() if
> you'd like to install a Miniconda Python environment. Execution
> halted'

I checked and the R Studio I am running shows as being 64-bit. I have also linked the Python interpreter in R Studio in 'Tools -> Projects Options -> Python'.

Could someone please explain what the problem might be, and how to get Python to work in R Markdown for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Use reticulate::install_miniconda()` like the error says and then see if the error still persists.

Comment: **RStudio** and **R** are 2 completely different things. Check that you are running **R** 64-bit